# Have trouble reading an iPhone crash log?

Tags: ios, crash-reports

My friend sent me a crash log after my app crashed on his device, but I'm not entirely sure what it means. Here's what i think it means - it's crashing because of a problem with the dispatch queue SetupTimelineThumbnails. Any further info I can get from that, or any way of seeing more specifically what the problem might be?

EDIT: This is the crash log after importing to XCode organizer. In an archived build I have the .dSYM but other than importing this, I don't know how to pair it, if it isn't already.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  3

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x398ec3e2 0x3982a000 + 795618
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3445195e 0x34449000 + 35166
2   CoreFoundation                  0x39880736 0x3982a000 + 354102
3   CoreFoundation                  0x39880682 0x3982a000 + 353922
4   App                     0x00103844 0xe9000 + 108612
5   App                     0x001029cc 0xe9000 + 104908
6   App                     0x0012e7f6 0xe9000 + 284662
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3286a78e 0x32869000 + 6030
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3286db36 0x32869000 + 19254
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3286b678 0x32869000 + 9848
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x3286e60e 0x32869000 + 22030
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3286e7d4 0x32869000 + 22484
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e0f7ec 0x36e09000 + 26604
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e0f680 0x36e09000 + 26240


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3982de1e 0x3982a000 + 15902
1   CoreFoundation                  0x398b2024 0x3982a000 + 557092
2   CoreFoundation                  0x398afd80 0x3982a000 + 548224
3   CoreFoundation                  0x39874c3c 0x3982a000 + 306236
4   Foundation                      0x37b9dd4e 0x37b74000 + 171342
5   Foundation                      0x37b9dbe6 0x37b74000 + 170982
6   App                     0x000f738e 0xe9000 + 58254
7   App                     0x0012e07c 0xe9000 + 282748
8   UIKit                           0x3509d534 0x3504f000 + 320820
9   UIKit                           0x35082354 0x3504f000 + 209748
10  UIKit                           0x350997f2 0x3504f000 + 305138
11  UIKit                           0x3505588a 0x3504f000 + 26762
12  QuartzCore                      0x39fe34e6 0x39fe0000 + 13542
13  QuartzCore                      0x39fe3088 0x39fe0000 + 12424
14  QuartzCore                      0x39fe3fac 0x39fe0000 + 16300
15  QuartzCore                      0x39fe3996 0x39fe0000 + 14742
16  QuartzCore                      0x39fe37a8 0x39fe0000 + 14248
17  QuartzCore                      0x39fe360c 0x39fe0000 + 13836
18  CoreFoundation                  0x398c193e 0x3982a000 + 620862
19  CoreFoundation                  0x398bfc34 0x3982a000 + 613428
20  CoreFoundation                  0x398bff8e 0x3982a000 + 614286
21  CoreFoundation                  0x39833238 0x3982a000 + 37432
22  CoreFoundation                  0x398330c4 0x3982a000 + 37060
23  GraphicsServices                0x3971e336 0x39719000 + 21302
24  UIKit                           0x350a6284 0x3504f000 + 356996
25  App                     0x000ea6ee 0xe9000 + 5870
26  App                     0x000ea6a4 0xe9000 + 5796

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a2bcd98 0x3a2ab000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e0fad6 0x36e09000 + 27350
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e0f7f2 0x36e09000 + 26610
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e0f680 0x36e09000 + 26240

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a2ac5d0 0x3a2ab000 + 5584
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3286fd22 0x32869000 + 27938
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3286b374 0x32869000 + 9076

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.App.SetupTimelineThumbnails
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a2bc350 0x3a2ab000 + 70480
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e37fb2 0x36e09000 + 192434
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e74366 0x36e09000 + 439142
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x387c6dda 0x387c3000 + 15834
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x387c4094 0x387c3000 + 4244
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34451a58 0x34449000 + 35416
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x387c4118 0x387c3000 + 4376
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x387c41b0 0x387c3000 + 4528
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x387c559a 0x387c3000 + 9626
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3445199e 0x34449000 + 35230
10  CoreFoundation                  0x39880736 0x3982a000 + 354102
11  CoreFoundation                  0x39880682 0x3982a000 + 353922
12  App                     0x00103844 0xe9000 + 108612
13  App                     0x001029cc 0xe9000 + 104908
14  App                     0x0012e7f6 0xe9000 + 284662
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x3286a790 0x32869000 + 6032
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x3286db36 0x32869000 + 19254
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x3286b678 0x32869000 + 9848
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x3286e610 0x32869000 + 22032
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x3286e7d4 0x32869000 + 22484
20  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e0f7ee 0x36e09000 + 26606
21  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e0f680 0x36e09000 + 26240

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a2abe30 0x3a2ab000 + 3632
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a2abfd0 0x3a2ab000 + 4048
2   CoreFoundation                  0x398c12b6 0x3982a000 + 619190
3   CoreFoundation                  0x398c002c 0x3982a000 + 614444
4   CoreFoundation                  0x39833238 0x3982a000 + 37432
5   CoreFoundation                  0x398330c4 0x3982a000 + 37060
6   WebCore                         0x35a46a80 0x35a3c000 + 43648
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e1a0de 0x36e09000 + 69854
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e19fa4 0x36e09000 + 69540

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a2bcd98 0x3a2ab000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e0fad6 0x36e09000 + 27350
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e0f7f2 0x36e09000 + 26610
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e0f680 0x36e09000 + 26240

Thread 3 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3b551524
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x003d5000      r6: 0x1dd4bb84      r7: 0x003d4c44
    r8: 0x1dd4bb60    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x00187a28     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x003d4c38      lr: 0x36e37fb7      pc: 0x3a2bc350
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0xe9000 -   0x1befff +App armv7s  <bfbf44f854863f9a86cf808b00ba9536> /var/mobile/Applications/CB5BADE5-F797-425E-BF52-1E8F3F005CC4/App.app/App
 0x2ba2000 -  0x2ba6fff  AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7s  <c21cac592f853fc09a46657db46d57bc> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
0x2fe86000 - 0x2fea6fff  dyld armv7s  <4047d926f58e36b98da92ab7a93a8aaf> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3123a000 - 0x3123ffff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7s  <063f79a2305230b89900c04b76378a30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x31265000 - 0x3126ffff  IAP armv7s  <f2e6932e29f53497b95c7e50c3f9923f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x3135d000 - 0x31385fff  PrintKit armv7s  <455c5c48113536f19941597829f5cc4c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x313f1000 - 0x31453fff  CoreText armv7s  <0bc6f711a1ac33d39aff94b25aaa0ca9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x31473000 - 0x314aefff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7s  <81be079eea38327bbc4359f51200d14b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31578000 - 0x315cefff  CoreAudio armv7s  <d143b508df8c3bc59d278db2b2b21383> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x315d1000 - 0x315d1fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <915a58cccb823b83ba03668d3007ce93> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x316b4000 - 0x316b6fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7s  <08d63fd4db4f3396811d3f3187467a51> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x317e1000 - 0x317e4fff  MobileSystemServices armv7s  <7f72cd5ef1ec364db87c3080862e3c13> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x317fe000 - 0x31800fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <25e4ca5ddce53ba5ba2736bed63237e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x31801000 - 0x31804fff  libcache.dylib armv7s  <9cf0ce4cf58b3e8586ded458cbc95220> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x31805000 - 0x318bafff  CoreImage armv7s  <696af88ae10237e581e8d07e1a59b6a0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x318d0000 - 0x318fdfff  MobileAsset armv7s  <7b114cd2611739d2a98b69b0023f1de0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x3193c000 - 0x31951fff  libmis.dylib armv7s  <18b87986181632268bf01c995df438bf> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x31983000 - 0x31984fff  CoreSurface armv7s  <bfa1ed28d7433ec5ad12745b93078f1e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x319ea000 - 0x319f6fff  GenerationalStorage armv7s  <5f33281960423a0abf8268cb6b9aab7f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x319f7000 - 0x319fefff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7s  <a896789233633fec91d00805d21f6cc3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x31b41000 - 0x31b44fff  libmacho.dylib armv7s  <ce836c624c3735079b8fe7bc0f72feca> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x31cbf000 - 0x31ccbfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7s  <128642f5406f38ffba77a8dc7a6d8626> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x31cf2000 - 0x31d16fff  Bom armv7s  <3edaffc2ff3138b6954fd2d22e355f2c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x31e8f000 - 0x31fccfff  vImage armv7s  <f2dd5658022d30198e860b960799d5da> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x3213d000 - 0x32144fff  OpenGLES armv7s  <387374ffea8f3408b35a5fba5e222539> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32145000 - 0x32190fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7s  <e8c6f2d59607309a81454875b7d93eb6> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x323aa000 - 0x323e9fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <bfcfd7a63ea53326b9b082d2446df88c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x32417000 - 0x3241cfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7s  <15974f7598923c18b960438d6974e425> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x32869000 - 0x32879fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7s  <2e16eff18cb734acbc785c17d8c3f234> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3298c000 - 0x3299efff  libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <912c72699619371ba4c373b6eb611bc7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x3299f000 - 0x329c0fff  AccessibilityUtilities armv7s  <85081e495275387598e297b8a78b8ba9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities
0x329cc000 - 0x32a52fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7s  <1e104301acc635fdad72e4131c710495> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x32abf000 - 0x32ac0fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7s  <e3345ca5bafc3df2b3fb8391cc4edc67> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x32ad4000 - 0x32ad7fff  MobileInstallation armv7s  <6691df41cfb435cda59a6128027475bc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x32afe000 - 0x32ca5fff  JavaScriptCore armv7s  <28a43291f5b63fe9ad803c4fb0035edd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x32e04000 - 0x32e08fff  IOSurface armv7s  <7f644c14a5fa3974b6aae0d8e4d0ae8a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x32e09000 - 0x32e37fff  Security armv7s  <9351745f735639b8942a016689073882> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x33328000 - 0x33340fff  EAP8021X armv7s  <a2da6cb7c51d3258a239891eda670136> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3338e000 - 0x3338efff  vecLib armv7s  <2fbed315030d36afb00557a01ef2b67b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x333d3000 - 0x333e4fff  SpringBoardServices armv7s  <df3a7b3919923ed3b76e44e73a7090c5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x333e5000 - 0x333ebfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7s  <7ea4bde974e83e06a8b3989b5f3c1031> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3343b000 - 0x3343bfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7s  <a3047fed3a583589bc1f9d5c68049da3> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33460000 - 0x3349ffff  VideoToolbox armv7s  <cf6e97840d3539d49aeb8d0725151862> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x334a0000 - 0x334a1fff  libdyld.dylib armv7s  <1133e18b4478308f95174734844e7cdb> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x334ad000 - 0x33645fff  MediaPlayer armv7s  <169a0a92b760331dae44a764d3635113> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x33803000 - 0x33818fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7s  <5310b06eb73a30fd8dbbbc7acc469d4a> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3392a000 - 0x33be0fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <353bf25ab0d7351ca5168b1818c52a47> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x33c9f000 - 0x33d1cfff  HomeSharing armv7s  <267e27e410a53e9da541c3f7c2c566d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x3411a000 - 0x34132fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7s  <98afac2b9acf30c8a946d4afa54a60a6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x34133000 - 0x34222fff  GeoServices armv7s  <fd66be0c386134aca3e1bb5414d1edd8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x34225000 - 0x3436efff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7s  <21afcbd26a6c3e31926ea9c2d8d31fc7> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x34374000 - 0x3439afff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7s  <016edc61ab923313991234f181ff8236> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x34449000 - 0x34547fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7s  <40751f7e35b234caafba6639cbaa0dcc> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3454a000 - 0x347d1fff  AudioToolbox armv7s  <1a06093bee1d310eb2e3fb356594ef36> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3485c000 - 0x34871fff  libxpc.dylib armv7s  <f1d00111e2403b58847450f12b7ab516> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x34874000 - 0x34874fff  Accelerate armv7s  <7f55d59e8dbc3675b1a4360f29fdc0f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x34942000 - 0x34948fff  MobileKeyBag armv7s  <dfd64f821a0138a490d05c4b3d01e7ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x34949000 - 0x3496dfff  OpenCL armv7s  <d124287f1bf03b2086e4be5b47414c46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x34997000 - 0x34a83fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <647bee17a96830faae7fc43e1884c64a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x34a84000 - 0x34a89fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7s  <c76159e71f3b3a52aa432af6f67d4a62> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x34a8a000 - 0x34ae2fff  CoreLocation armv7s  <c6e83df07a6c36c6b940c6524221f3d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x34ae3000 - 0x34af0fff  TelephonyUtilities armv7s  <88aa5948c53b36169c6df76cabeedd63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x34b86000 - 0x34b92fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7s  <e915389b3e38376791fac27ca2a14088> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x34c17000 - 0x34cc4fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7s  <038b15f2b7c63712b612c0787615e060> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x34dd8000 - 0x34dd8fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7s  <6fcdcd97e9f032aaa9b60461ceb13284> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x34de5000 - 0x34df4fff  CoreVideo armv7s  <f683995a6e66390bb80f81515947314f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x34fcf000 - 0x35034fff  CoreMedia armv7s  <8265880a81c13b119a3fa270ec9ae460> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3504f000 - 0x355a1fff  UIKit armv7s  <29801ef497b2323e8a98e0c141f7e4a0> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x355d6000 - 0x3578afff  CoreData armv7s  <75872d32d14f37fcbe25940f0ef457c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x357cc000 - 0x357dafff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7s  <d0f685e4b7db31ba900a7dd91091fa38> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x35869000 - 0x35880fff  BackBoardServices armv7s  <89be2b0c43cd3930ba8ac3a30ac9738e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x35881000 - 0x3594bfff  Celestial armv7s  <63911ba5bed3340eac6320c060763931> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x359b9000 - 0x359c2fff  MobileWiFi armv7s  <ea9ace74d9663b208a80030a219a9d68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x359c3000 - 0x359defff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7s  <abb25846493f3533bc5a0d330436820d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x35a3c000 - 0x3636cfff  WebCore armv7s  <657870f4c9e23bd3b2a66edf73ca86e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x3640d000 - 0x36410fff  AggregateDictionary armv7s  <0475f4c9cdc0340a821dae7783ef1d5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36a9a000 - 0x36aadfff  AirTraffic armv7s  <f3beacefc02d388ea40485b5eca64b2e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x36b19000 - 0x36b1efff  CommonUtilities armv7s  <d6a401a9773b3eddbf1254207b1e6609> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x36b36000 - 0x36b3afff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <c22689d09e313ab08e82086f25e020fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x36b77000 - 0x36b77fff  liblangid.dylib armv7s  <f5bb9330c5293a5d8bd03fb19b08aaff> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x36e09000 - 0x36e8ffff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7s  <d25f5cb4e6aa3e7e8928b97d1296ea4d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x36f46000 - 0x37359fff  FaceCoreLight armv7s  <1533bd4f300b344283a1c0f2fbf1ac36> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x37432000 - 0x3743bfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7s  <ded1e960c8ac3cf094137d5bb8da2dc4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3743e000 - 0x3743ffff  libremovefile.dylib armv7s  <2f1fdfc7535f391a8f3eeacd82407f0d> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x379e3000 - 0x37a3bfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <0ec7c11a75b73fd5a396ba1a3751d0f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x37a90000 - 0x37acafff  iTunesStore armv7s  <2328b672a907396dbc7dbf707c56aa3d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x37acb000 - 0x37b17fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7s  <70004197c40a37c2b3addd15bdf23ada> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x37b45000 - 0x37b4cfff  XPCObjects armv7s  <388eb3736d793edf84303f5076737e6a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x37b74000 - 0x37d36fff  Foundation armv7s  <ce14923f5b5d30f8ada732293c0e3ef8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x37d7c000 - 0x37e58fff  WebKit armv7s  <362b2fa6841437a89970d5e350a62a5f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x37e59000 - 0x37e5bfff  TCC armv7s  <4356ca2596fb3b6dabd2db08925d7165> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x37eb1000 - 0x37f09fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7s  <da174a94b3af3481b9dee3cf9e719b86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x37f6c000 - 0x38059fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7s  <a27fa7116c8c3b9486c6726a4f580242> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3805a000 - 0x38063fff  MediaRemote armv7s  <561bac350ae63afaad64b6aead3f3278> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x38085000 - 0x380a1fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7s  <310cc335e10a3beb938b2147cf2983b0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x38416000 - 0x38564fff  MusicLibrary armv7s  <d01fd2b4c7953b01a00cd40f070c255d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x386cf000 - 0x386d5fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7s  <59bcc37c4062396ba9d2614592849dce> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x387c3000 - 0x387d6fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7s  <4a187bebe5353c038ed99c3b211a9893> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x387d8000 - 0x3882dfff  CoreTelephony armv7s  <8452232eeba332ab8df0e983cc4646ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x38830000 - 0x3887cfff  IMFoundation armv7s  <205e8778b9963a9d8e55b6c8080bf704> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x38a59000 - 0x38a59fff  libunwind.dylib armv7s  <6b55d71acd1c3aaab309855377445cc6> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x38c40000 - 0x38ce0fff  UIFoundation armv7s  <f62dc3c023b83d8fa9471d54e4a67fc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x38ce1000 - 0x38ce8fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7s  <54c15d3db48531119a9c5c6d1ce6d23b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x38dd6000 - 0x38ddffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7s  <7bd9ef027eee3c30b932ac9ccfad2b26> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x38de0000 - 0x38e00fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7s  <d5b9c2c6876c35aa8fc11a6e9cf951aa> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x38e0a000 - 0x38e0ffff  liblaunch.dylib armv7s  <e7af690e65903c85a8bd5d1e95d41664> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x38e3b000 - 0x38e3cfff  DataMigration armv7s  <491f30b9946f3023a1e7140ef569b305> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x38e3d000 - 0x38e45fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7s  <c0be967a01b93f439a82d2ad89e1ad27> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x38e46000 - 0x38e85fff  SystemConfiguration armv7s  <79422f6496e13885ae6370aa65f13155> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x38e86000 - 0x38ebcfff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7s  <a61af54e5e473e2e88e6745891bd31d9> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x38f81000 - 0x38f97fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7s  <071f376981a53e69b1fc41c01e8e92d8> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x39077000 - 0x39122fff  MediaControlSender armv7s  <848c5281ddc63c2abffcb920a88fbf67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x39147000 - 0x39280fff  CoreGraphics armv7s  <667bf12f24cd350299f36cc71e4a9ef5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x39359000 - 0x39431fff  StoreServices armv7s  <fb22825e814e3542b4547103b29aecbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x39603000 - 0x39609fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7s  <47f7e2f908023cd0b376ab2216881145> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x39630000 - 0x39716fff  AVFoundation armv7s  <840770e2b2a93a0ead9782aead45657d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x39719000 - 0x39724fff  GraphicsServices armv7s  <66b9208b8f1d32229a4957a56375152a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3976a000 - 0x39787fff  PersistentConnection armv7s  <ac5005684e36383096e439d840f0ee10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x39821000 - 0x39828fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7s  <79275e7173d3396da07c5af6b8d73c4e> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3982a000 - 0x3995cfff  CoreFoundation armv7s  <b59e2456dc863cfe853b2101d90fa974> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3996b000 - 0x3996cfff  IOAccelerator armv7s  <034f09d31bc23d928d837741ffffff5c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x3998c000 - 0x3998dfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7s  <927eb7343a8531979a4065262928c344> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x399a4000 - 0x399bdfff  DictionaryServices armv7s  <c96adbc2c8ec390aaf6c1312dc91b632> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x399d3000 - 0x399d3fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7s  <4850aef547de37a78c8ce0a61e4e3f99> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x39b1b000 - 0x39b8ffff  ProofReader armv7s  <ec06c705f1e83ba3997d78060cb7e052> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x39b9d000 - 0x39bbbfff  WebBookmarks armv7s  <d3c84a2c2dae3226abe1697ec25ccf2e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x39bfb000 - 0x39c36fff  AppSupport armv7s  <24f40c0f426937b4b481f5eb497d0d06> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x39c3d000 - 0x39d01fff  CFNetwork armv7s  <e51abfda7a5039a783fbd5cf84b06b41> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x39d10000 - 0x39f95fff  MediaToolbox armv7s  <ffe42d2b233c332fb01eadad55c3414f> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x39f96000 - 0x39fdffff  IOKit armv7s  <ed0ccdd9000e3908a5969f9026e575d2> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x39fe0000 - 0x3a0f4fff  QuartzCore armv7s  <71f2f6e216403b5aa4fd186574f0d985> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3a0f5000 - 0x3a14efff  MobileCoreServices armv7s  <f4f013a8379e3af080d8bd852e1d0c00> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3a217000 - 0x3a29efff  CoreMotion armv7s  <ce9de8a02a8130eeb9915639a765b380> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x3a2ab000 - 0x3a2c1fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7s  <dc5563b496c539348db839fe00c8ee08> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3a300000 - 0x3a4d8fff  ImageIO armv7s  <2c1cff5d59cf3c11a1f73c0301fe02dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3a4ef000 - 0x3a4fbfff  libz.1.dylib armv7s  <e2e7d8cd69183ea99a5cb0fc00b20217> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your crash log has not been symbolicated. You need the dSym file that was generated when you made the build.

You might find this a useful start: [Technical Note TN2151: Understanding and Analyzing iOS Application Crash Reports](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Comment: According to that, apparently xcode automatically stores the dSym file upon each Archive. But when I drag the crash log from my desktop into xcode organiser, it shows exactly what I have above. Pressing re-symbolicate doesn't show anything more neither.

Comment: Do you still have the exact build that generated the crash log in your Archives in Xcode?

Comment: The `Last Exception Backtrace` on top is formatted in a way, the symbolication script won't symbolicate that part anyway. But let's do one step at a time. Please add full crash report that is formatted in a way it is readable and that shows all information without going into edit mode. So we can help you find the app dSYM on your Mac and guide you through.

Comment: You can check if you have the matching dSYM available via Spotlight (that's how the symbolication script searches it): `mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == BFBF44F8-5486-3F9A-86CF-808B00BA9536"`. (The value is taken from the `Binary Images` section and reformatted to uppercase and 8-4-4-4-12) Check if that is available. The report is still missing the full header, which shows report version, iOS version, etc. Without that symbolication will not work.

Comment: Ah, It does have those lines, I just removed the top 12 lines from SO for the privacy of the person who submitted the report.

Comment: @Kerni I do have the .dSYM file, I can see it once i go on 'show package contents'. How do I link it with my crash report?

Comment: These lines don't contain any person/privacy related information. You can't "link" it, is that one found via the command I posted? Or does the command return no result?

Comment: Copy and pasting it into spotlight, as in the magnifying glass in the top right corner of my mac? It shows no results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17646/discussion-between-kerni-and-andrew)